# Zooming to cursor position in SVG documents

Tags: javascript, html, svg

Trying to zoom to the cursor's position. I'm translating the image as I zoom (scale), but haven't got things working properly.

If you try the demo, you'll not that if you zoom to one location, the move the mouse and zoom to another location, the circle jumps.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nadirabid/f06n05ep/9/

```js
function setCTM(element, matrix) {
  var m = matrix;
  var s = "matrix(" + m.a + "," + m.b + "," + m.c + "," + m.d + "," + m.e + "," + m.f + ")";

  element.setAttributeNS(null, "transform", s);
}

var svgEl = document.getElementById('svg');
var zoomEl = document.getElementById('zoom');
var zoomScale = 1;

svgEl.addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {
  var delta = e.wheelDeltaY;

  zoomScale = Math.max(0.5, zoomScale - (delta / 2200));
  zoomScale = Math.min(zoomScale, 1.5);

  var p = svgEl.createSVGPoint();
  p.x = e.clientX;
  p.y = e.clientY;

  p = p.matrixTransform(svgEl.getCTM().inverse());

  var zoomMat = svgEl.createSVGMatrix()
    .translate(p.x, p.y)
    .scale(zoomScale)
    .translate(-p.x, -p.y);

  setCTM(zoomEl, zoomMat);
});
```

```css
svg {
  background-color: #eee;
}
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" width="400" height="400">
  <g id="zoom">
    <circle r="40" cx="200" cy="200"></circle>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you are replacing the old matrix completely without taking into account the previous "zoom history".

What you should be doing is reading (or remembering) the old matrix and then apply the new translate and scale operations to that.

Comment: Thank man! Sweet and short. Got the working version here: http://jsfiddle.net/nadirabid/f06n05ep/12/